# Oracle - Compare two similar tables in same database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables `PROD_DEMO` and `PROD_IMP` in the same oracle database. Both share the same structure and constraints. Both table has a primary key `PROD_CODE`.

I have to show all the records from `PROD_IMP` table with one addition column `STATUS` showing if the record is updated or added in the `PROD_IMP` table.

I have written below query to achieve this but I am sure this require some improvement to make it faster.

```
select imp.*, decode(c.record_count, 2, 'U', 1, 'A', null) from prod_imp imp
left join
    (Select prod_code, count(1) as record_count from
        (
            (SELECT * FROM prod_demo UNION SELECT * FROM prod_imp)
            MINUS 
            (SELECT * FROM prod_demo INTERSECT SELECT * FROM prod_imp)

        ) group by prod_code) c 
on imp.prod_code = c.prod_code;
```

I know this query will also list records which are deleted from `PROD_DEMO` table but in my case that won't happen.

The execution plan is shown below:

[image]

Both tables can have thousands of records. Now my question is how can I improve the performance of this query.

Comment: Your query doesn't meet your requirement to show all `PROD_IMP` records. It only shows added or altered ones.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that if the record is present in prod_demo but not in prod_imp, it is added. If present in both, and any field has changed, then updated. The query below may or may not improve performance depending on the size of the tables, and number of matching records. The inner select with union, interest and minus requires that every field from every record in both tables be examined multiple times, and cannot leverage any indexes. The below example attempts to minimize the number of full record comparisons by only comparing all the fields from records present in both tables.

```
-- Inserts
select d.*, 'A' [status]
from prod_demo d
left join prod_imp i on d.prod_code=i.prod_code
where i.prod_code is null

union

-- Updates
select d.*, 'U' [status]
from prod_demo d
join
(
    select prod_demo.prod_code,count(1)
    from
    (
        select prod_imp.*
        from prod_imp
        join prod_demo on prod_imp.prod_code=prod_demo.prod_code
        union
        select prod_demo.*
        from prod_demo 
        join prod_imp on prod_imp.prod_code=prod_demo.prod_code

    ) matches
    group by prod_demo.prod_code
    having count(1) > 1
) updates on d.prod_code = updates.prod_code
```

Comment: This will not tell if a row has been updated in `prod_imp` table or not.

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward way is to select from `prod_imp` (because it is demanded to show all its records) and look up `prod_demo` in order to determine each record's status:

```
select 
  i.*,
  case when d.prod_code is null then 'added'
       when decode(i.col1, d.col1, 0, 1) = 1
         or decode(i.col2, d.col2, 0, 1) = 1
         or ... then 'updated'
       else 'unaltered'
  end as status
from prod_imp i
left join prod_demo d on d.prod_code = i.prod_code;
```

This should be about as fast as it can get.